# How get navigation control from a button?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I know if I used a view controller I can use this:

```
var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this.NavigationController);
```

How do I know what navigation I am using inside of button I need use?

```
public class BarReaderButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        // I tried this but don't worked
        var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this.NavigationController);

        // I tried this but do
        var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this);

        Element.Clicked += async(s_, e_) => {
            // Setup our button
            // Tell our scanner to use the default overlay
            scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;

            //We can customize the top and bottom text of the default overlay
            scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode to scan";
            scanner.BottomText = "Barcode will automatically scan";

            //Start scanning
            var result = await scanner.Scan ();

            HandleScanResult(result);
        };
    }
}
```

I can't use this code inside a button render. Or did someone this before?

The project is a shared application for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

The code for creating the scanner should stay inside the view controller/activity/page. You can still use the custom button and add the code you need to the Clicked event handler.

```
var myCustomButton = new BarReaderButton();

myCustomButton.Clicked += async(s, e) => {
        var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
        scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;

        //Start scanning
        var result = await scanner.Scan ();

       //Do something with the result
    };
```

If this is Xamarin.Forms you will also have to use platform specific code inside the Page code as the barcode reader requires a Context on Android:

```
#if __IOS__
var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
#elif __ANDROID__
var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(Forms.Context);
#endif
```